# GitHub Copilot - please login to github and try again

Tags: github, github-copilot

For Intellij plugin, GitHub Copilot shows error `please login to github and try again`.

I have already done the following:

- Authenticated GitHub Copilot with my GitHub user and password.
- Allowed GitHub Copilot in GitHub account profile.
- Restarted the IDE multiple times after the plugin installation.
- I have license for Github Copilot.

What should I do to resolve this error?

Comment: Please state what versions you're using and confirm that you have a license for copilot.

Comment: The process was eventually resolved after uninstall/reinstall of the GitHub Copilot plugin.

Comment: I'd like to add that it is entirely possible your company is blocking access, like mine does. No error is shown. It just tries to connect and then disconnects.

Comment: just updated to v1.2.5.2507 for jetbrains and getting this issue again, seems it was working ok for a while but the problem is back and constantly have to do this log out restart dance. Really annoying for a premium plugin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Debanjan Basu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1472196/debanjan-basu) suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73242748/github-copilot-please-login-to-github-and-try-again/73245220#comment133597486_73245220):

> logout, restart IDE and login again.
> You might have signed up for copilot after the session was initiated

---

You have multiple discussion reporting this error.

[discussions 18132](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/18132) includes:

> Behind corporate proxy. Used latest stable version with [CLion 1.1.28.1744](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17718-github-copilot/versions/stable/190492) and added `-Dcopilot.agent.disabled=true` to Custom VM properties.
>
> Also delete `github-copilot.local.xml` and `github-copilot.xml` in `.config/JetBrains/CLion2022.2/options`.

---

This has since [been answered](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/29127) by GitHub staff member [Benjamin Muskalla](https://github.com/bmuskalla) ([Aug. 11th, 2022](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/29127)):

> We’re happy to announce that the latest release of Copilot for Visual Studio Code and Copilot for IntelliJ contains preliminary support for connecting through HTTP proxy servers.
>
> The current version supports basic HTTP proxy setups, with and without basic authentication.
>
> ### For Jetbrains IntelliJ
>
> - Ensure you have Copilot for **IntelliJ 1.1.29.1869** or higher installed in your IDE.
> - Setup the `HTTP proxy` in your Preferences.
> - Restart your editor so the proxy configuration is applied correctly to all components requiring connections via the proxy.
>
> [image: IntelliJ -- Screenshot 2022-08-03 at 20 24 31]
>
> ### For Visual Studio Code
>
> Ensure you have **Copilot for VS Code 1.39.6432** or higher installed in your editor.
>
> - To set up your proxy, go to your VSCode Settings and ensure your `HTTP proxy` configuration is set up properly.
>   Alternatively, Copilot uses the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` variables from your environment.
>   [image: VScode -- Screenshot 2022-08-11 at 10 18 49]
> - Restart your editor so the proxy configuration is applied correctly to all components requiring connections via the proxy.

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: @c-an I am sorry to read that. Can you describe your setup? What IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using Android Studio - Electric Eel.

Comment: @c-an The [2022.1.1 edition](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases), I see. Do you see [error messages similar to this?](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/18132).

Comment: No, I have no message alert but when I open Copilot panel, It says, Please Login to GitHub and try again. Even though I login, it doesn't go away.

Comment: @c-an OK. What Os are you using? And are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @c-an logout, restart IDE and login again. You might have signed up for copilot after the session was initiated.

Comment: Can the IDE get an update to do this for us? It's been almost a month. Tagging anyone at jetbrains....

Comment: @rollsch good question. Let me know if you get an reply from support, I will update this answer.

Answer (score 49):

I have to restart my IDE, then go to tools->GitHub copilot:

1- restart IDE

2- got to "tools" -> "GitHub copilot" -> "login to GitHub"

3- it will show you a popup with code, click on copy and open to add and trust your device.

[image]

Comment: Wow, they really dropped the ball on this UX. Thanks!

Comment: Genius! thank you1

Comment: This is the solution exactly! Thanks for it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after I quit my personal trial period and got access from the organization. Restarting didn't help, and logging in/out didn't work at all for some reason.

I uninstalled the plugin completely, restarted IDE, and installed it again and after another restart, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I did Invalidate caches and then it worked for me (since the issue happening after trying to login to github copilot)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I experienced a similar issue where I couldn't initiate the GH login process. It seems that the likely cause of this problem was the incompatibility between the operating system (Windows 11) and my hardware configuration (Ryzen 5 1600 and TPM 1.2). To resolve the issue, I successfully downgraded my OS to Windows 10, and now everything is functioning smoothly without any login problems.