# PyCharm 2023.3.1. Failed to initiate the GitHub login process. Please try again

Tags: pycharm, github-copilot

For the past few days I keep getting this prompt when I try to log into Github Copilot via my copy of PyCharm Professional 2023.2.1:

> Failed to initiate the GitHub login process. Please try again.

On my laptop hooked up to the same JB license, no such problem occurs. I have tried uninstalling, disabling and enabling, and just waiting, but nothing has worked. Below I paste the data of my setup:

OS: Windows 11 Pro 22H2
IDE: Pycharm Professional 2023.2.1
Plugin: Github Copilot 1.2.22.3129

My computer, nor the IDE does not stand and does not connect to any proxy, neither does my ISP, Government, or anyone else block access to this service.

Answers to that question didn't work: [GitHub Copilot - please login to github and try again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73242748/github-copilot-please-login-to-github-and-try-again)

Answer (score 0):

After several days of attempting to reach out to GH and JB support, I have decided to format my PC and install Windows 10. I suspect that Windows 11 was causing issues on my PC due to compatibility problems with my CPU (Ryzen 5 1600) and TPM 1.2. Now that I'm back on Windows 10, I can successfully log in to GH without any issues.